# How can I run multiple statements in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, testing, multiline, ghci

I'm doing some very simple performance testing of a simple function that I believe has O(n)(squared) performance (or worse).

Currently I'm running multiple statements which is tedious to repeat:

```
ghci> myfunction 0 100
true
ghci> myfunciton 0 200
true
ghci> myfunction 0 300
true
ghci> :r
```

Is there a way I can run all four **GHCi** statements? I can't just combine them using "native" Haskell as I'd like to include the `:r` (which is a GHCi statement - not exactly Haskell) that gets run at the end.

Comment: I would not recommend doing performance testing with GHCi, as the results can be very different from (or even opposite to) the real results when compiling with optimizations enabled.

Comment: I do recall reading about this, however in this particular case my code is probably doing something like O(n)(squared) - so it's fairly easy to replicate the behavior with GHCi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom GHCi command using `:def` in this way:

```
> :def foo (\_ -> return "print 100\nprint 200\n:t length")
> :foo
100
200
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
```

In the returned string, `:`-commands can be included as well, like `:t` above.

Answer (score 4):

One way I've found is creating a separate file:

```
myfunction 0 100
myfunction 0 200
myfunction 0 300
:r
```

and then using:

`:script path/to/file`

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to create a testing suite in your Cabal file in which you place your function calls as tests, then use `stack test --file-watch`. That recompiles and reruns the tests every time you save a file.

Comment: What about `:r` which is not a function but a GHCi statement.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski The effect of `:r` is to reload the file, now every time you save a file, it will reload the file.